# javascript error when compare two number

Tags: javascript

When I call this function a strange error occurs.

So I added two sentences in my code to find out what was the problem.
First one is `alert(result);` in 6 line
and the second one is `alert(wordbook_info_percentage+">="+result);` in 12 line
then I execute my code and I found out that result variable is "100.0" and
`"wordbook_info_percentage>=result" condition in "info_change_frame"` function becomes true when `wordbook_info_percentage is 2.0 and result is 100.0`
I can't understand why `2.0>=100.0` is true. What is my mistake?
Please help me.

```
function word_book_info_change_1(){
    var wordbook_info_percentage=parseFloat(($('#wordbook_info_1').text()).replace('%','')).toFixed();
    arr[0]=43;

    var result=parseFloat((parseInt(arr[0])+parseInt(word_number))*100/parseInt(arr[1])).toFixed(1);    
    alert(result);

    var info_change_1_repeat=setInterval(info_change_frame,10);

    function info_change_frame(){
        if(wordbook_info_percentage>=result){
            alert(wordbook_info_percentage+">="+result);
            ClearInterval(info_change_1_repeat);
        }
        else{
            wordbook_info_percentage=(parseFloat(wordbook_info_percentage)+0.1).toFixed(1);
            $('#wordbook_info_1').text(wordbook_info_percentage+"%");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
"2.0">="100.0"
true
2.0>100.0
false
parseInt("2.0")>parseInt("100.0")
false
```

i think you should parse the value to int .

```
function word_book_info_change_1(){
    var wordbook_info_percentage=parseFloat(($('#wordbook_info_1').text()).replace('%','')).toFixed();
    arr[0]=43;

    var result=parseFloat((parseInt(arr[0])+parseInt(word_number))*100/parseInt(arr[1])).toFixed(1);    
    alert(result);

    var info_change_1_repeat=setInterval(info_change_frame,10);

    function info_change_frame(){
        if(parseInt(wordbook_info_percentage)>=paseInt(result)){
            alert(wordbook_info_percentage+">="+result);
            ClearInterval(info_change_1_repeat);
        }
        else{
            wordbook_info_percentage=(parseFloat(wordbook_info_percentage)+0.1).toFixed(1);
            $('#wordbook_info_1').text(wordbook_info_percentage+"%");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are converting those numbers to string with `number.toFixed(1)`. Comparing strings with numbers uses radix sorting, that is the reason why you are confused by the comparation.

Just move the `toFixed` call to the end where you set the value to some DOM.

```js
var a = 12.345;
var b = 5.35;

console.log(a, b);
console.log(a.toFixed(1), b.toFixed(1));
console.log(a > b);
console.log(a.toFixed(1) > b.toFixed(1));
```